# How to use FCM pkg on Django?

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the fcm_django package to send notifications API to Firebase but I have some confusion about those two concepts on Firebase like so: (**registeration_id** and **device_id**)

https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#setup

I placed the "server_key" of Firebase to registration_id but don't understand what does device_id means and what is the value I should put on it?

after answering the above questions I tried to send notification from Django by the admin page on Django by creating registration_id which is "server_key" and defining the type which is a "web", but when I created this object I didn't see any message has been sent to Firebase cloud.

Note:-

I want to send notifications to only one device not many users.

so, can anyone help me to achieve this mission succeeded?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `device_id` is a token that is generated by the Firebase SDK on each device/app combination that wants to receive messages from FCM.

To learn how to access this token, have a look at the documentation for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token).

Once you have the token on the specific client, you will need to send it to a place where the `fcm-django` package can then also access it; typically a cloud hosted database, such as the Realtime Database or Firestore that are also part of Firebase.

From there your Django can then get the token, and pass it to the `fcm-django` API.